# Reprinting a picking list to a printer and not to screen via X++

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I am trying to automatically print a picking list directly to the printer.  It has already been picked.  Here is a job that prints it, but it keeps going to the screen and not to the printer.

```
static void JobReprintPickingList(Args _args)
{
    Args args;
    ReportRun reportRun;
    SalesFormLetter salesFormLetter;
    PrintJobSettings printJobSettings;
    RecordSortedList list = new RecordSortedList(tablenum(WMSPickingRoute));
    WMSPickingRoute wmsPickingRoute = WMSPickingRoute::find('PkR 079256');
    ;

    if(!wmsPickingRoute)
        return;

    list.ins(wmsPickingRoute);

    args = new Args(ReportStr(WMSPickingList_OrderPick));
    args.designName("Standard");

    printJobSettings    = new PrintJobSettings();
    printJobSettings.deviceName('HP Universal Printing PCL 6');
    printJobSettings.setTarget(PrintMedium::Printer);
    printJobSettings.preferredTarget(PrintMedium::Printer);

    salesFormLetter  = new SalesFormLetter_PickingList(false);
    salesFormLetter.updatePrinterSettingsFormLetter(printJobSettings.packPrintJobSettings());

    args.caller(salesFormletter);
    args.parmEnum(PrintCopyOriginal::Original);
    args.parmEnumType(enumnum(PrintCopyOriginal));
    args.object(list);

    reportRun = new ReportRun(args);
    reportRun.init();
    reportRun.run();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  I had to add this line:

```
printJobSettings.lockDestinationProperties(true);
```

This force it to the printer anway.

Comment: This solved my issue, was running print code as a batch so it couldn't be displayed to screen which was why it was failing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code to use OriginalPrint like this :

```
args.parmEnum(PrintCopyOriginal::OriginalPrint);
```

The problem lies on the method loadPrintSettings of class FormLetterReport that overrides the target to screen when you use Original or OriginalCopy.

Comment: This worked too for one way to do it.  I'm doing some funky printing stuff so this won't always work.  Gave you an upvote though thanks!